# can any one suggest how to pass a Dynamic list from one form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi all can any one suggest how to pass a dynamic list which contains some elements which i want to display in second form on form 1 button click...

AS some post are already there for this question but none of then are solved till now, can any one help me in this?

I tried this way.

```
      public List<string> final_input
      {
        get { return final_input1; }
        set { final_input1 = final_input; }
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        final_input = new List<string>(Class_Grid_opr.final_input_list.ToList());
        Take_INput_form tcn = new Take_INput_form(this);
        tcn.ShowDialog();

    }
```

in second form i tried to use that list with the object of main form but unable to get elements of list its returning empty list..

In simple words one from has a list which has few elements i want to pass that list to from 2 on button click....

sorry for bad english ,please help me..

Comment: does your `Take_INput_form` have some property to hold a reference to `your list from Form 1`?

Comment: @KingKing i didn't get your question?

Comment: If you understand my question, you will know how to deal with your problem. I mean you can define some property in your `Take_INput_form`, then in the `button1_Click`, just assign the list you want to that property. In your `Take_INput_form`, you can perform some check if that property is not null to use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this probs below code worked for me....

```
Take_INput_form tcn = new Take_INput_form(listname);
  tcn.ShowDialog();
```

in form 2 during initilisation

```
 public Take_INput_form(List<string > input)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Final_input_display(input);
    }

    public void Final_input_display(List<string> temp)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <temp.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = temp [i];
        }
    }
```

if any one has better solution than this please post...

Comment: What happened to parent window (this) parameter?

Comment: This is also a kind of passing data between classes. I think you can use it if it's enough. No better solution here because it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add new property to the form and initialize it

```
Take_INput_form tcn = new Take_INput_form(this);
tcn.FinalInput = final_input; // Add FinalInput property to Take_INput_form
tcn.ShowDialog();
```